# Compose failed to render preview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

The preview doesn't work when using stringRes() to load string from resources, and shows the following error:

Failed to instantiate Composition local

This preview was unable to find a CompositionLocal. You might need to define it so it can render correctly.

Comment: Could you provide the code of your Composable?